# Continuity test if statment

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I have an if statement that looks something like this:

```
if ($(window).width() < 799) {
    $('.element').css({'display': 'none'});
} else { 
    $('.element').css({'display': 'block'});
}
```

I would like to continuity test the statement so that when the window is resized, it would go back to normal (or the other way around). I have tried `setInterval` however that does not seem to work nor does it seem like the right thing to do. I'm aware that I can use css media queries for some of this, but some of the code not show can not be done in css.

Comment: Use the event that causes the value to change.

Comment: You already have jQuery. so why not use .hide() and .show()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    $('.element').toggle( $(this).width() < 799 );
}).trigger('resize'); // <- fires this on pageload as well
```

Comment: Sorry if this is a silly question but can I put anything within that function like $('.element').css({'display': 'none'}); or a if statement. And does this trigger every time with window resizes?

Comment: Yes, you can put anything in that function as long as it's valid, and it triggers everytime the window is resized, in all browsers. Note that toggle() does exactly the same as what you're suggesting, it toggles the visibility of the element based on a boolean.

Comment: It should be `$(this).width() > 799` in this case: http://jsbin.com/ICoGEC/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `window.onresize` event https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onresize

```
window.onresize = function(){
    $('.element').css('display', $(window).width() < 799 ? 'none' :'block');
}
```